# Azure function Path issue after published

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am using azure function app V3 and I am reading an excel from `Data folder` in the same project.
I have set `Copy-always` for excel and it's been copied into bin folder.
So In code I'm referring path as
`var binDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`

but after publishing the `Data folder` is out side `bin folder` and my code is unable to find the excel.
Path of my excel after publish:-
`C:\home\site\wwwroot\Data`

path my code is looking at:-
`C:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\Data`

[Kudu Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpkac.png)

Is there a generic way to make path to work in local and after published to azure.

Any help is appreciated!! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `ExecutionContext context` parameter in your function method, the use the code below:

```
    public static void Run(other parameter, ExecutionContext context)
    {
        string templatePath = Path.Combine(context.FunctionAppDirectory, "Data");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks :), It worked for me in local and after publishing as well.